# Which Unix tool for Pixel-art -generation?

Tags: graphics

I have had problems to generate pixel art for a game where units are of specific sizes such as 55x55 (not geometry but by pixels i.e. 55 pixels by 55 pixels). I have tried Gimp where I have misread many-times the sizes with the select tool -- it is irritating to get a bit too distorted size. Then I have used Inkscape that works actually quite good -- you generate the vector-image and select it and then you go to `"Export to bitmap"` where you can specify the size (this same feature is probably also in Blender, probably as easy). Anyway I am looking for something more powerful like having helper color-palettes easily or automatically-done perhaps like [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Ut37BIDXW0) with Gimp. I can find a variety of tools mentioning pixels but I hope you to point out the best before trying all of them.

```
$ apt-cache search pixel|wc
     99     861    6029
```

> **Perhaps related**
>
> 1. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7860/how-can-i-adjoin-images-with-imagemagick-for-pixel-art
> 2. Some example with Photoshop [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-faR9_CKho&feature=endscreen&NR=1),
>      create pixel art by reusing basic things such as hands, hairs and
>      bodies (create separate files for them).
> 3. A pixel-art competition [here](http://lpc.opengameart.org/).
> 4. Using blender for generating stuff [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/how-to-create-a-rolling-ball-with-python-in-blender) programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [mtpaint](http://mtpaint.sourceforge.net/), which is a quite handy Paint-like app which was designed for drawing pixel art:

> mtPaint is a painting program which Mark Tyler developed from scratch so he could easily create pixel art and manipulate digital photos.

[image: mtpaint screenshot]

As for automatic generation, likely you will have to develop something using ImageMagick or another programming language.